Compiling error could not find the task ‘Maui:build’
When trying to run my .net Maui project in visual studio code on Mac it keeps giving me the error could not find the task ‘Maui: Build’
I have delete and redownloaded all the files for vs code however I am still getting the same problem

Press cmd+shift+p and search for devices and see if you can find them if not, your run and debug is not configured

I have been getting the same since I updated to macos 15.0/xcode 16.0 / installed iOS 18 emulators.
After downloading a fresh copy of the “dotnet/maui-samples” repo I am still getting the error. I can debug Swift just fine to emulators or devices. The more interesting thing is that I can still make my release build using my bash script (dotnet publish ….)
My best guess is that whatever generates the task.json or launch.json files is either busted or not finding some dependencies
It seems that “Xcode 16 is not supported yet” per Maui and xamarin githubs
Update: workaround found if you updated already…. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/1449

Great answer.  This solved the problem for me.  TY!  I would suggest that you state in your answer:  "Disabling 'xaml hot reload' in the vscode settings provides a workaround as described in this github issue:..."

It seems that “Xcode 16 is not supported yet”, I guess we'll have to wait for the update.
